# Django - in debug.py list index out of range

Tags: django

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Please help.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 280, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 674, in **call**
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in **call**
    response = self.get_response(request)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 142, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 166, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 58, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 109, in get_traceback_html
    frames = self.get_traceback_frames()

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 228, in get_traceback_frames
    pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(filename, lineno, 7, loader, module_name)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 209, in _get_lines_from_file
    context_line = source[lineno].strip('\n')

IndexError: list index out of range

can it be due to using notepad++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this answer is a bit late but it could help others :)

In my case, that was because I didn't restarted apache and the old files where used and conflicted with the new (I don't know how though). A simple apache restart fixed the problem (graceful should work too I think).

In a general way, it seems the error occurs when there is a conflict in the files and not a problem from your code. Try removing the pyc files, restarting django, apache or what is currently using your python code right now.

That worked for me.

Comment: i thought i did apache restart as well but when I saw this post I tried "stop" run `ps -ef | grep http` (osx) there were still bunch of httpd process running. So I completely killed httpd process. then started solved the problem

Comment: Same here, needed to *restart* and not *reload* uwsgi after a Django upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The source file contains Macintosh line breaks (\r) that is not supported by the djangos debug page.

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13958#comment:5

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and most advice on Stackoverflow was to either a) delete *.pyc files and restart the webserver or b) check for Macintosh line breaks (for Mac users).

Both didn't help.

The error turned out to be fairly trivial. For some reason for "DEBUG=True" I was getting this error in my httpd log files, but when I changed "DEBUG=False" I started getting the *actual* error in the log files instead. So at least in my case this was a false error in the sense that you were not seeing the real problem because of something to do with the DEBUG=True/False switch.

In short, try **DEBUG=False** if it's set to True or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is very odd.  Get a hexdump utility and see what bytes are in the source file.  Perhaps a byte order mark at the start of the file?