# SyntaxError invalid syntax (views.py, line 52) 

Tags: django, list, syntax, view

Do you know why does it say invalid syntax in the return line? Everything seems to be ok I checked. I have replaced tabs with spaces if indentation is a problem.

```
def detail(request, sl):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.filter(slug=sl)[0]
        try:
            previous_post = post.get_previous_by_published()
        except:
            previous_post = ""
        try:
            next_post = post.get.next_by_published()
        except:
            next_post = ""
    return render_to_response('blog/detail.html',{'post':post,
                                                  'next_post':next_post,
                                                  'previous_post':previous_post,
                                                 },)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for invalid syntax, try removing the ',' (comma) in the end of the return statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm, you're opening three `try`s and only have two `except`s... you need to catch that first `try` before the `return`

Comment: If you're not currently using a linter of some kind (a plugin which checks syntax for you) then you may find it very useful for tracking down bugs like this. Indeed, I highly recommend SublimeText (http://www.sublimetext.com/) and the Sublime Linter plugin (https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter), which will auto-lint as you code.

Comment: No, I am not using. Thanks, I will check them out!

Answer (score 0):

list index seems to be on the line

```
post = Post.objects.filter(slug=sl)[0]
```

If you know that your query would return a single result then don't use FILTER, replace it with GET and along with it use try except.

```
try:
    post = Post.objects.get(slug = sl)
except:
    pass #something
```

else you could simple do

```
try:
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug = sl)[0]
except IndexError, e:
    pass #something
```

Comment: the question has been CHANGED after I uploaded the answer :|

Comment: Hey I say your answer after I edited the question. It was ok, this here was the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257414/django-in-debug-py-list-index-out-of-range but I still get the invalid syntax at the render line error though.

Comment: Sorry I was browsing at the same time and that showed up, thought it would be a good idea to change it not to confuse people and lead a discussion in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a RequestContext in your return statement

```
from django.template.context import RequestContext

return render_to_response('blog/detail.html',{'post':post,
                                              'next_post':next_post,
                                              'previous_post':previous_post,
                                             },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: The problem is still there! I really don't understand, all my other view functions are written in the same way and yet just this is not working.

Comment: I don't have any logger implemented in this site (I am a beginner to django)